# GAS FURNACE NOT STAYING LIT

Tags: electrical

I have a brand new goodman furnace and tryed to turn it on and it stays on for a minute then turns off and it is blinking 4 flashings lights i read the manuel but really does not tell me much and i also tryed to r4eset it but no luck on that either any advise we do not have a tect in our small town

Comment: What model is this furnace?

Comment: 4 flashes is usually the high limit switch. But if it lights and doesn't stay lit, I'd blame the flame sensor as usual, but it's a new unit: that shouldn't be the problem. Does it actually light, or are you just seeing the glow from the HSI get hot? - Turn the switch off and take the panels off to get the model number. It should be on the inside of the lower door.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Who installed this, and why won't the installer fix it? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.